# Calling a non-bean property method in FreeMarker

Tags: javabeans, freemarker

In Freemarker we typically do stuff like this..

```
class User{
private String name;

public String getName()...

pubilc void setName(String name)....

}
```

Then our Freemarker code calls the property name like this...

```
<strong>Hello ${user.name}</strong>
```

How about if we want to call a method in user called "generateUserToken" like this?

```
class User{
private String name;

public String getName()...

public void setName(String name)....

public String generateUserToken(){
  return "Hello World";
}
```

}

Now if I try to call the Freemarker code like this I get an error...

```
<a style="font-size: 20px" href="${obj.generateUserToken}">VIEW USER</a>
```

> Caused by: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression
>   obj.generateUserToken is undefined on line 63, column 36 in
>   user_page.ftl.

Does this mean all methods Freemarker accesses (using the default BeanWrapper) must conform to bean property naming conventions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do `obj.generateUserToken()` in templates. Note the `()`; without that you just get the method, but don't call it. But there's some other problem in your case because it says "generateUserToken" is undefined. It's most certainly that the method doesn't come from a public class or interface.